# Recognize date format '14-August-2020 12:30:42' as type datetime

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert a datetime column in format '2020/08/14 12:30:42' to a datetime column with format '14-August-2020 12:30:42' using the following function:

```
select
*,
date_format(starttimecet,'%d-%M-%Y %h:%i:%s) as test

from table
```

While this function in successful in doing that, the '14-August-2020 12:30:42' format of the test column no longer recognizes it as a datetime column. Is there a way to have a column in this format but still have it recognized as type datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once you convert your bona fide datetime literal into a text *string*, it is no longer datetime.  Your current query is actually along the lines of what you should be doing in general.  Specifically, you should keep the original datetime column throughout your query as needed, and then display the text you want in the final outer select.